# Swift: Can't set StatusBarStyleLightContent

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uistatusbar

This is really weird, I have page view controller with onboarding flow and I cannot set the white color in status bar.

I added "Status bar style" with "UIStatusBarStyleLightContent" value in info.plist along with appropriate line in AppDelegate

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

Despite making these two steps I keep getting black status bar.

Maybe this is something with Xcode 6.3? Did any of you encounter such a weird issue? If yes, how to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just added these four lines into my Info.plist

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

After that I didn't even needed to set anything from code.

Comment: This is quite the same I did in info.plist i guess

Comment: @DCDC Quite, because without setting UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance to false it won't work-

Comment: @DCDC so set both of them, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your ViewController :

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Comment: should I create new class? Or where should I paste this code?

Comment: New class. it replaces the basic UINavigationController that you are using.

Comment: Ok, then do sth more, import somewhere this class or just create it and the whole rest will be handled?

Comment: If you are using storyboards, select the navigationController in it, and assign it to your new subclass. Like when you assign a TableViewController to a custom subclass...

Comment: And if you are instantiating an instance of UINavigationController, just replace it by an instance of your new subclass

Comment: I'm not using nav controller so far. What if it was a single view app, this must be a way to set the status bar light

Comment: Sorry then, I misread your post....  then just use `preferredStatusBarStyle()` it in your ViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow below steps.

1. Set the View controller-based status bar appearance to NO in the .plist file.
2. UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

Answer (score 0):

The perfect and working way to make StatusBar LightContent.

1) Go to info.plist and add property 'View controller-based status bar appearance' = NO

2) In your AppDelgate.swift, put this code:

```
application.setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

This definitely works! Try it and let me know, if you face any issues.